Print title\subject while export grid control content to a pdf or excel file
I want to print the title/subject while export the grid control content to a pdf or excel file. And I had tried to use: MainView.OptionsPrint.RtfPageHeader = "title", but this string will appear at "each" page while I only expected shown once at the begin of the exported file. So I'm just wonder:
Can I let it only show at the head of page? (i.e. as a title not header) (p.s. pdfOptions.DocumentOptions.Subject = "Document Subject"; not working)
If I want to put a string at the end of the whole exported pdf file(only once not footer), what should I do?
